# Setting the character set

Tags: python, firebird

I have a Firebird database in ISO-8859-1 encoding, but I can't seem to get the right way to set it in my connection.

I have tried:

```
conn = fdb.connect(dsn='mydatabase.fdb', user='***', password='***', charset='latin_1')
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Error while connecting to database:
- SQLCODE: -924
- bad parameters on attach or create database
- CHARACTER SET LATIN_1 is not defined', -924, 335544325
```

Trying `iso-8859` gives `unknown encoding: ISO-8859`.

How can I set my Firebird connection to `ISO-8859-1` character encoding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I found the right way is to use `iso8859_1`.

Comment: See also [Firebird Language Reference, Appendix F: Character Sets and Collation Sequences](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-appx06-charsets.html), or `select * from RDB$CHARACTER_SETS`